# Adjust carburettor without hi-speed adjustment

Tags: fuel-system, carburetor, small-engine, two-stroke

I've got a Walbro WA226 with no hi-speed adjustment screw.  Unfortunately, it seems that the issue is in the high-speed jet.  Adjusting the low screw can set me up so long as the throttle is at full, but in order to run it at idle, I have to screw the low screw back in a full turn.

How can I go about adjusting it?  Would I have to bend the tab that connects to the metering diaphragm?

Comment: Perhaps the carb just needs to be cleaned. If it didn't come with the adjustment, it must not require it for proper function. Permanent changes are permanent.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I have cleaned it as best I can with aerosol carb cleaner.  There is a plug on the place where the high-speed screw would be, but I am unable to get it out.

Comment: The aerosol cans do almost nothing, you have to pull the carb off and soak it unfortunately. In the past, I've found outdated, but new-in-box carbs for like $10 on ebay. That's worth a check too.

Comment: Yep, I did take it off, took off all gaskets and metal parts that I could get off and soaked it in cleaner and sprayed out all ports available: it's spic and span as far as I can get to.

Comment: It's not impossible the high-speed jet is gunked a bit, but like I said, I am unable to get the plug out.  I have a replacement, so it must be possible, but I haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: You missed what I was saying. It doesn't have a high speed needle because it doesn't have a high speed jet. It's one jet from what I find in diagrams. Pull it back off and get *real* carb cleaner soaking solution.

Comment: Ok, I see.  Is there really a difference between aerosol and "real" cleaner solution?

Comment: Come to think of it, that makes more sense.  It's just that the carb is still labelled "H" and "L", with the "L" next to the adjustment screw and the "H" next to the copper plug.

Comment: They likely repurpose the shell for different models. I can't speak to chemical composition, but from visual appearance and results; yes, it's an entirely different solution. The stuff is extremely strong, read the directions for soak time.

Comment: Take a look here it has a description of the high speed circuit stage.  I had used this link a year or so ago when fixing a chain saw carb.  [Walbro carbs flow](http://www.drystacked.com/Walbro%20Carburetor%20Theory%2027Jun2010.pdf)  They are basically non adjustable for models without a HI screw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you can bend the tab**

The metering diaphragm enriches the entire range on every circuit.  If the fuel level is higher it will require less vacuum under [**Venturi's Law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect) to pull the fuel from the 'float'.

You can use the metering diaphragm float tab as a method to enrich all of the circuits and then adjust your low speed circuit with the fuel screw to lean out your 'idle' or low speed circuit to create a balanced AFR.

[**Here is a detailed article**](http://www.helifreak.com/showthread.php?t=326599) on how each circuit functions.

Comment: YES. Do this if you want it to idle, but run too rich when throttled up. Venturi's Law? Come on, man. This carb doesn't even have a float.

Comment: @justinm410   It has a float mechanism with a needle and seat.  Venturi's Law applies with all carburetors.

Comment: It's not a float. A float is a float and a diaphragm is a diaphragm. They're an entirely different mechanism. There's an underlying problem that needs to be fixed. Bending tabs is going to richen across the range just messing it up elsewhere. It also may be irreversible.

Comment: There are two circuits.  High and low.  If you richen the carb globally you can lean out the low speed when the high speed is the proper AFR.  I have two of these carbs and the method described is the method recommended. If you disagree, please provide citations.

Comment: Look, it's your/his funeral. It doesn't even have a high speed needle as discussed above, so apparently, you do not. People break their stuff every day. I am just fine letting you guys do so. Also, it's the recommended procedure rather than cleaning your carbs properly? What a crock.

Comment: That's pretty dramatic.  Perhaps you should provide the correct answer.  Once the tab is bent, it sounds like from you statements, that the Zombie Invasion will sweep across the planet and we will all die.  Post your advice as an answer.  Thus far your an art critic more than a resource.

Comment: Interesting, just read in Paul Dempsey's book that when you fit a new transfer lever, lever adjustment can be *necessary*, with recommendations on how to do it.

Comment: @anonymous2   There you have it.  Good luck.  You can always bend the tab back.  :-)

Comment: Update: it worked.  I bent the tab away from the carb body, adjusted the low-speed, and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

**Perform routine maintenance on your carburetor.**

It doesn't have a high speed needle or float.

If the tabs needed to be bent, they would have bent them in the factory.

Comment: Part of the recommended tuning of the carburetor and all carbs based upon metering diaphragms with a needle and seat is to bend the tab.

Comment: @DucatiKiller you're spreading misinformation. You really should reconsider... ya know, or at least look up a diagram of the carb we're talking about.